# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getConnectionProvider()

Tags: spring, hibernate, nosuchmethoderror

I'm using spring 3.0.5.RELEASE and hibernate hibernate-core version 3.6.8.Final with JSF 
in runing my server tomcat 7 I have this exception

```
Grave: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [application-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getConnectionProvider()Lorg/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:607)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getConnectionProvider()Lorg/hibernate/service/jdbc/connections/spi/ConnectionProvider;
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(SessionFactoryUtils.java:90)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet(HibernateTransactionManager.java:252)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 21 more
```

this is my application-context.xml in my project Maven :

> bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
>             
>             
>             
>             
>         
>         
>             
>             
>                 
>                 .........
>
> ```
>           </list>
>       </property>
>       <property name="hibernateProperties">
>           <props>
>               <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
>           </props>
>       </property>
>   </bean>
>   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
>       <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
>   </bean>
>   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
>   <context:annotation-config/>
>   <context:component-scan base-package="fr.ensa.agadir"/>
>
> </beans>
> ```

Comment: You have a library issue. Check your versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you have hibernate 4.0 jars in your classpath then you should use `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` instead of `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`

If your classpath does not have hibernate 4.0 jars then remove all hibernate jars and add hibernate 4.0 jars and use *org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean*.

Comment: i have this in my pom.xml 
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.6.8.Final</version>
   <type>jar</type>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>

Comment: Change the version and artifact id accordingly or add JARS manually in WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0):

You have a Spring version that's not compatible with your Hibernate version.

If you are using Maven run

```
 mvn dependency:tree
```

and look for all occurrences of the hibernate jars.

Usually it's because you have both Hibernate 4 and Hibernate 3 jars in your class path.

Bonne chance!

Comment: Where there maven run.to execute mvn dependency: tree

Comment: I think he is not using MAVEN.

Comment: If you are using maven that command must be run where your pom.xml is located.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Run it in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

use hibernate4 instead of hibernate3

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>
```